# Redirect domain to domain via hosts or alternative

Tags: windows, hosts

Using the Windows `hosts` file (or alternative method or software), is possible I redirect a "local domain" (like "mydomain") to another domain (instead of an IP), like `google.com`? With it, if I access `http://mydomain/` it will redirect (transparently or not) to `http://google.com/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you effectively noted, just putting  mydomain probably won't work for google or any other site that has multiple DNS names associated with a given IP (and/or multiple IP addresses).  If you wanted to run a lightweight webserver, you could either configure it to reverse proxy another site (i.e. if you go to http://mydomain, the reverse proxy would pass that request to the real site and return it to you) or you could configure it to issue a 302 redirect.